# ASP.NET MVC 4 Websecurity.CurrentUserId returns -1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using SimpleMembership in my ASP.NET MVC 4 Project. After I login, I am unable to get the current UserName and the current UserId, here is my Login function:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(FormCollection form)
        {
            bool success = WebSecurity.Login(form["username"], form["password"], false);
            if (success)
            {
                string returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
                if (returnUrl == null)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/home/index?userId=" + WebSecurity.CurrentUserId + "&userName=" + WebSecurity.currentUserName);
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

On this line `Response.Redirect("~/home/index?userId=" + WebSecurity.CurrentUserId + "&userName=" + WebSecurity.currentUserName);` 
`WebSecurity.CurrentUserId` returns `-1` and `WebSecurity.currentUserName` returns `""`

Am I missing something? Any help would be much appreciated.

However in my View if I do this `@{ int value; value = WebSecurity.currentUserID; } @{ ViewBag.Title = value; }` the title in my browser is the correct currentUserId

Comment: Why do you need to add those items to the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
[HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Login(FormCollection form)
            {
                bool success = WebSecurity.Login(form["username"], form["password"], false);
                if (success)
                {
                    var userId = WebSecurity.GetUserId(form["username"]);
                    string returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
                    if (returnUrl == null)
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("~/home/index?userId=" + userId + "&userName=" + WebSecurity.currentUserName);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Response.Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                return View();
            }
```

WebSecurity will not internalize until the redirect is complete (by design). A way around it is to get the userID via username on successful login

Comment: What is the LoginModel? when I add it, I get a namespace error

Comment: my answer was suited for MVC ASP.net. let me update it for you

Answer (score 1):

MSDN:

> When a user is logged in, ASP.NET sets an authentication token in a
>   cookie that lets ASP.NET know on subsequent requests that the user has
>   been logged in. If persistCookie is false, the token is valid only
>   until the user closes the browser.

So it can only be used on requests after your login. Use:

```
WebSecurity.GetUserId(username);
```